# Parse two files and generate employee data

Tags: java, sql, file, bufferedreader, filereader

Say we have two log files with comma separated values. The `file1.txt` represent the `employee id` and `employee name`, `file2.txt` represents the `employee id` and the `projects` he associated with.
`file1` is having unique entry. `file2` will have many-many relation. New employees dont have any entry in `file2.txt` if he doesn't assigned any projects.

```
File1.txt:(EmpId, EmpName)
1,abc
2,ac
3,bc
4,acc
5,abb
6,bbc
7,aac
8,aba
9,aaa

File2.txt: (EmpId, ProjectId)
1,102
2,102
1,103
3,101
5,102
1,103
2,105
2,200
9,102

Find the each employee has been assigned to number of projects. For New employees if they dont have any projects print 0;
Output:
1=3
2=3
3=1
4=0
5=1
6=0
7=0
8=0
9=1
```

I used BufferedReader to read a line from `file1` and compare it with each line from `file2`. Below is my code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader file1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
        BufferedReader file2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
        BufferedReader file3 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
        HashMap<String,Integer> empProjCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int lines =0;
        while (file2.readLine() != null) 
            lines++;
        String line1 = file1.readLine();
        String[] line_1 = line1.split(",");
        String line2 = file3.readLine();
        String[] line_2 = line2.split(",");
        while(line1 != null && line2 != null)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for(int i=1;i<=lines+1 && line2 != null;i++)
            {
            if(line_1[0].equals(line_2[0]))
            {
                count++;
            }
            line2 = file3.readLine();
            if(line2 != null){
                line_2 = line2.split(",");
            }
            }
            file3 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
            empProjCount.put(line_1[0], count);
            line1 = file1.readLine();
            if(line1 != null) line_1 = line1.split(",");
            line2 = file3.readLine();
            if(line2 != null) line_2 = line2.split(",");
        }
        System.out.println(empProjCount);
```

My questions are,

1. Is there any way to optimize it less than O(n^2), without using any extra space?
2. I used 3 BufferedReader to read a `file2.txt`, as once we read a line, it moves to next line. Is there any other option to mark the current line?
3. If we considered this as a table, what is the best way to query the above scenario?

Comment: SO is not the best place to ask for a code review

Comment: Why do you tag it `sql` if you don't use any `SQL`? In SQL it's a simple `select emp.EmpId, count(*) from emp left join proj on e.EmpId = Proj.EmpId group by emp.EmpId`

Comment: Performance: `n` being the number of records in file1 and `m` in file2, it can be done either in `O(n*m)` with `O(1)` memory, or in `O(n+m)` with `O(n)` memory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: @Stultuske@JimGarrison I didn't post my code to review. I just posted it to show my approach and I did some work on this. My actual question is how to approach it in different ways. Let me know if still it doesn't belongs here.

Comment: @irs102info your questions point clearly to a review, in which you want us to check how you can improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

For 1: yes.

For 2: yes:

I would do it in two iterations:

1. Iterate on the IDs (file1) and initialize a map (empId, projectCounter)
2. Iterate on the projects (file2) and for each line update (projectCounter++) the corresponding entry in the map.

In that way you will have almost linear execution time (for file1 and file2 size).

Answer (score 1):

Gather a `Map` of all employee IDs from `file 1` and initialise it to contain `0` for the project count.

```
    // Build my map of all employees.
    Map<Integer, Integer> employeeProjectCount = Arrays.stream(file1)
            // Get empId - Split on comma, take the first field and convert to integer.
            .map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.split(",")[0]))
            // Build a Map for the results.
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    // Key is emp ID.
                    empId -> empId,
                    // Value starts at zero.
                    empId -> ZERO
            ));
```

Walk through `file 2` counting the projects.

```
    // Walk the projects list.
    Arrays.stream(file2)
            // Get empId - Split on comma, take the first field and convert to integer (again).
            .map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.split(",")[0]))
            // Count the projects.
            .forEach(empId -> employeeProjectCount.put(empId, employeeProjectCount.get(empId)+1));
```

Printing it:

```
    // Print it.
    System.out.println(employeeProjectCount);
```

gives

> {1=3, 2=3, 3=1, 4=0, 5=1, 6=0, 7=0, 8=0, 9=1}

BTW: I worked with the files as `String[]`s.

```
String[] file1 = {
        "1,abc",
        "2,ac",
        "3,bc",
        "4,acc",
        "5,abb",
        "6,bbc",
        "7,aac",
        "8,aba",
        "9,aaa",};
String[] file2 = {
        "1,102",
        "2,102",
        "1,103",
        "3,101",
        "5,102",
        "1,103",
        "2,105",
        "2,200",
        "9,102",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Files.lines` and regular expressions:

```
Pattern employeePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<id>\\d+),(?<name>\\s+)");
Set<String> employees = Files.lines(Paths.get("file1.txt"));
    .map(employeePattern::matcher).filter(Matcher::matches)
    .map(m -> m.group("id")).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Pattern projectPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<emp>\\d+),(?<proj>\\d+)");
Map<String,Long> projects = Files.lines(Paths.get("file2.txt"))
    .map(projectPattern::matcher).filter(Matcher::matches)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.group("emp"), Collectors.counting());
```

And to print the results:

```
employees.stream()
    .map(emp -> emp + "=" + projects.getOrDefault(emp, 0L))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```